# how to get First not null/empty values in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Hi I have doubt in excel
how to get First not null/empty values when valid value available else display empty value that field in excel
[image]

input data :

```
 Empid |Name
    1  |1
    2  |
    2  |c
    1  |
    3  |
    4  |i
    5  |g
```

based on above data I want output like below :

```
Empid |Name 
1     |1
2     |c
3     |
4     |i
5     |g
```

[image]

please tell me how to achieve this task in excel.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have ***Excel-365*** then try below formulas.

`D2` cell formula `=UNIQUE(A2:A8)`
`E2` cell formula `=@FILTER($B$2:$B$8,($A$2:$A$8=D2)*($B$2:$B$8<>""),"")`

[image]

Comment: I have tried 2 systems using Filter and Uinque Function .one system related excel not showing this functions. another system have this function but filter function showing only first row expected values remain fields showing #NA. can u please help on it.

Comment: Can you show the formula screenshot to your post. It should work as I already shown a screenshot of working formula.

Comment: hi I have posted in main question .first row only getting values remain fields values getting incorrect .plz clarify on it

Comment: You have to use absolute reference. Try `=@FILTER($B$2:$B$8,($A$2:$A$8=D2)*($B$2:$B$8<>""),"")` You do not have dolor sign in `$A2:$A$8=D2` it will be `$A$2:$A$8=D2`. You do not put dolor sign in front of 2.

Comment: @harnithu Also in `$B$2:$B8` it will be `$B$2:$B$8`. Copy and paste formula from my answer.

Comment: Maybe a small adjustment could be: `=@SORT(FILTER(B$2:B$8,A$2:A$8=D2,""))`. +

Comment: @JvdV I thought about this. Thanks for suggestion.